# AlertDialog Button text formatting is completely wrong on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am currently using an `AlertDialog` to prompt the user and ask for a rating.  It works exactly how I would expect it to when using the AS emulator (Nexus 5 API 23).

From Emulator:

[image]

However, I tested the dialog out on my friend's device, an LG Stylo (Android 5.1.1, Api 22) and the formatting is completely wrong.  The button are in the wrong order and aren't formatted correctly at all.

From LG Stylo:

[image]

I am not sure how to go about ensuring that the formatting is correct for an `AlertDialog` and I honestly have no idea why the formatting isn't correct on the LG Stylo, and unfortunately I do not have another device to test it on currently.

Thanks in advance!

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.rateMeText)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.rateMe, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMIND_ME_LATER, false);
                        editor.commit();
                        try {
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(myContext.getString(R.string.playStoreMarketLink) + APP_PNAME));
                            myContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(myContext.getString(R.string.playStoreHttpLink) + APP_PNAME));
                            myContext.startActivity(intent);

                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.noThanksAndDoNotAskAgain, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (editor != null) {
                            editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMIND_ME_LATER, false);
                            editor.commit();
                            /*editor.putBoolean(KEY_DONT_SHOW_AGAIN, true);*/
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.remindMeLater, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        editor.putLong(KEY_LAUNCH_COUNT_PRESSED_REMIND, launches);
                        editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMIND_ME_LATER, true);
                        editor.commit();
                        System.out.print(sharedPrefs.getLong(KEY_LAUNCH_COUNT_PRESSED_REMIND, 27727));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
```

Comment: Have you tested it on emulator with API 22 i.e. 5.1.1 ?

Comment: Are you using `android.app.AlertDialog` or `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`?

Comment: If you dont set a style the device will sometimes use its own default style even when you set the apps theme. Its kind of a crap shoot if you dont set styles.

Comment: use android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of android.app.AlertDialog.

Comment: then after you can style your alert dialog in style.xml

Comment: @ErShani Thanks you, that worked perfectly!

Comment: @DanielNugent You too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a style using an existing one as a parent and then use it in the AlertDialog.Builder() method.

It would look like this:

```
<style name="myAlertStyle" parent="AlertDialog.Material">
    <item name="fullDark">@empty</item>
    <item name="topDark">@empty</item>
    <item name="centerDark">@empty</item>
    <item name="bottomDark">@empty</item>
    <item name="fullBright">@empty</item>
    <item name="topBright">@empty</item>
    <item name="centerBright">@empty</item>
    <item name="bottomBright">@empty</item>
    <item name="bottomMedium">@empty</item>
    <item name="centerMedium">@empty</item>
    <item name="layout">@layout/alert_dialog_material</item>
    <item name="listLayout">@layout/select_dialog_material</item>
    <item name="progressLayout">@layout/progress_dialog_material</item>
    <item name="horizontalProgressLayout">@layout/alert_dialog_progress_material</item>
    <item name="listItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_item_material</item>
    <item name="multiChoiceItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material</item>
    <item name="singleChoiceItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material</item>
</style>
```

and then you would just use AlertDialog.Builder() like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.myAlertStyle);
```

Comment: By the way you can always look in the sdk on your machine and see how all the default styles are created. Thats where I got this sample from :) They live in 'pathToYourSdk/sdk/platforms/android-##/data/res/values/'

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that this is pretty much a bug in the api-22 support library, since it tries to put all of the buttons on one row. It has been fixed in the api-23 support library by switching to the new layout with each button on it's own row.

I tested your code using a support library AlertDialog, and on a device with KitKat 4.4.4, in two different projects.

The same code for both tests:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("If you like this app, please rate it on the Google Play Store!")
                .setPositiveButton("Rate me!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No thanks and do not ask me again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Remind me later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

First, in a project with this gradle configuration (all api-22 settings):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Then, in a different project with this configuration (all api-23 settings):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testprojecttwo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

This is the result of the same code:

[image]

So, one fix for this would be to use the api-23 support library.